# Suggestions for a long lasting operation for testing purpose

Tags: c#

What operation could I uses that would simulate a relatively costly process

```
public void SimulateLongProcess()
{
   //Do Something that takes a few seconds to perform on a quadcode CPU
}
```

I want to avoid any thread waiting or so, neither involve IO. Some Math operation could do...

Comment: What's wrong with `Thread.Sleep`?  If you wanted to do something more exciting, you could calculate pi, but this is a test so I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could ask questions/for precisions and wait for answers before downgrading. I have my reasons, this is just a specific part for some more complex CPU unit tests we are conducting. Thread.Sleep is costly in terms of time but it is "fake" i.e no real processing is involved. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @mika jacobi  while(!booleanvariable){} where booleanvariable is set at end of process process. i dont know if this is correct method, just a suggestion.

Comment: @DILi unfortunately an empty while loop does not involve processing per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you need. You may do the following, on my machine it takes around 2900 ms. This code will not ensure the exact execution time, the execution time will differ on different machines. You may want to tweak it to your need.

```
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            double test = 1000; 
            test = (test * 100000.00001)/100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;
            test = (test * 100000.00001) / 100000.123123;

        }

        stopWatch.Stop();
        var executionTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: This is not very elegant, but it works. I'll try to make it recursive.

Comment: @MikaJacobi, I think this approach is not elegant at all, and it will not ensure a dependable delay or event test the execution, but may be you are looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

As a very dummy thing you could just run a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
    var str = "dummy";
}
```

`Thread.Sleep` would be more precise. Make sure you use it only for testing

Comment: Whats the use of `var string`?

Comment: @Duane you have to do something like assigning a value otherwise it will complete in no time

Comment: @fenix2222 Agreed. But I am preferably looking for something a bit less obvious like some math calculation.

Comment: I get that part but i don't understand the use of `var` in conjunction with `string`, why not just use `string` or `var` alone? Not having a dig, this is a genuine question just fyi

Comment: Sorry, instead of string I meant str, typo

Comment: Ahh gotcha, thought that looked a little odd ;)